# Aspose. Apply horizontal alignment for Range of Cells in Excel Documnet

Tags: java, excel, aspose

I am using Java Aspose library. And for particular Range of Cells in Excel Document I need to apply horizontal left alignment.

This is the way how I receive Range:

```
Range range = sheet.cells.createRange(startRow, startColumn, endRow - startRow + 1, endColumn - startColumn + 1)
```

That is the way I chose for setting horizontal aligment:

```
    Style style = sheet.workbook.createStyle()
    style.horizontalAlignment = 1

    StyleFlag flg = new StyleFlag()
    flg.horizontalAlignment = true
    range.applyStyle(style, flg)
```

I suppose this is not the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following sample code segment using Aspose.Cells APIs that works fine as I tested:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
Range range = sheet.getCells().createRange(startRow, startColumn, endRow - startRow + 1, endColumn - startColumn + 1);

        Style style = workbook.createStyle();
        style.setHorizontalAlignment(TextAlignmentType.LEFT);

        StyleFlag flg = new StyleFlag();
        flg.setHorizontalAlignment(true);

        range.applyStyle(style, flg);
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.